Relative energy use for a given compressor at different atmospheric pressures higher than 1 bar
I am involved with a problem that has to do with air or gas compressors but need to know if there might be a formula for energy use at different atmospheres or does it make no difference so long as it acts just the same as at normal atmosphere pressure. This all stems from the idea of compressors in situations not commonly experienced operating in very high gas pressure environments.  Gas supply at given pressures would be unlimited.
